# The placement of "just" and the sentence meaning

Tags: meaning, adverbs, adverb-position

Consider the two sentences, please:

> I **just** want to add a few details.
>
> I want to add **just** a few details.

How does the meaning change depending on the placement of *just* within the sentence?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) All I want to do is to add some details. (2) I want to add only a few details, not a lot.

Comment: Yes and amen to the ever-wise @KateBunting.

Comment: _Just_ in this construction means, and behaves like, _only_, which has a focussed NP (_a few details_) as the direct object. Therefore _only_ can go immediately before its focus, or immediately before any constituent that contains the focus, thus licensing _I just want to add a few, I want to just add a few,_ and _I want to add just a few_. All the same in meaning, different only in pronunciation.

Comment: I dispute that they are all the same in meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add a few details

- I want to add a few details, and that's all I want to do
- I hope my adding a few details isn't an imposition*
- I want to add a few details and I don't care about anyone or anything else

I want to add just a few details

- I want to add a small number of details
- I hope my adding a few details isn't an imposition*

YES, the idiomatic uses of "just" can make both word locations mean the same thing. The deferential or passive-aggressive use of "just" might relate to the sentence as a whole